# Whether i could use my laptop's monitor as mac mini's output display

Tags: mac-mini, laptop-display

I have a laptop(Acer 4743) and a mac mini 2012,Now i want to use laptop's LCD monitor as mac mini's output display, I know this maybe sound weird,But does anybody done this before or anybody know if it could work.any suggestion is very previous for me.

Comment: Remote desktop.

Comment: Thanks,But how about the performance?And is that stable?I hope to use something like VGA/HDMI or any others interface to do the connector.You know,The laptop monitor is also a kinda of monitor,right?

Comment: It's stable, I use a similar setup with my firewall, a Sun IPX, and my Macbook Pro

Comment: OK,How about the performance,Do you have any detail tutorial of using <quote>setup with my firewall, a Sun IPX <quote>

Comment: HI,I just download a VNC software and use it to control the mac mini in laptop,Even though it works,But i find when i swipe the mouse or drop MAC's window,It didn't responsed immediately,While there two PC are in a same local internet,Is there anything i need to do(likewise special setting)to improve the performance? I am using RealVNC